# Pthreads: Need Help understanding the output of my last thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to understand how pthread works.
I have a little boolean function to check for prime numbers. 
I have a little struct for the input data for the threads and i have function for the threads. 
When i set the input value for my prime function to 5 for all of the 5 threads. Threads 0-3 output true (is a prime number) but the last thread outputs false. My question is why?

(disclaimer: i followed the code from tutorials point. still new to coding so not totally sure if it is ok to post it like this here)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_THREADS 5

// Here is the prime function

bool prime(int n)
{   
    if (n == 1) { return false; };
    if ((n == 2) || (n == 3)) { return true; };
    if ((n % 2 == 0 ) || (n % 3 == 0)) { return false; };

    int sqrt_n{ 0 };

    sqrt_n = sqrt(n);
    
    int i{ 5 };
    
    while (i <= sqrt_n) {
        
        if (n % i == 0) return false;
        
        i += 2;
    }
    
    return true;
}

// the struct for the thread_data 

struct thread_data {
   int  thread_id;
   int  number;
};

// thread function

void *worker(void *threadarg) {
   struct thread_data *my_data;
   my_data = (struct thread_data *) threadarg;
   
   cout << "Thread ID : " << my_data->thread_id << "\n";
   cout << "Thread Prime : " << prime(my_data->number)<<"\n" ;
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main () {
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   struct thread_data t_d[NUM_THREADS];
   int rr;
   int i;

   for( i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ ) {
      t_d[i].thread_id = i;
      t_d[i].number = 5;
      rr = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, worker, (void *)&t_d[i]);
      
      if (rr) {
         cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rr << endl;
         exit(-1);
      }
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the erroneous output?

Answer (score 2):

The code is in fact (*almost!) working as intended. but you are being misled by the fact that output from your various threads is interleaved, see [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lZosS2eF36VtjPLM).  You therefore do not see what you are expecting.

To fix this, accumulate *all* of the output from a particular thread in a buffer and then output it all in one go, like this:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Thread ID : " << my_data->thread_id << "\n";
ss << "Thread Prime : " << prime(my_data->number) <<"\n" ;
std::cout << ss.str ();
```

Then, [it works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MsRXlAqeh65CSeoc).

Incidentally, C++ now has [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread), which is easier to use than pthreads and is portable across different operating systems and is therefore to be preferred.

Also `sqrt_n = sqrt(n);` should probably be something like `sqrt_n = sqrt(n) + 1;`, since truncating from floating point to `int` rounds down.

---

(*) See Nate Eldridge's answer for your other problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble reproducing your bug at first, but I eventually managed to do so using `-fsanitize=thread`: one or more of the threads can end up with bogus data, and it's not just a result of the output being mixed.  Adding a `sleep(2)` to the worker makes it easier to see, as does printing out the value of `my_data->number` (you can see totally nonsensical values like `22077`, which is indeed not prime).

I think the problem is that the main thread doesn't join the worker threads before exiting.  So it may exit while the threads are still running.  When it does, its stack, which is where the `t_d` array was  located, becomes invalid and may be overwritten with garbage.  The workers may then read this garbage when they dereference their `my_data` pointers.  (Of course, it is also possible for this to fail in other ways besides reading garbage, such as a segfault; it's undefined behavior and anything could happen.)

In `main`, you should loop over the threads and `pthread_join` each one before exiting or returning.  Or, if you really do want to let the main thread exit first, the `t_d` array should be made `static` or global.

Note this bug was already present in the tutorial code at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm - it's definitely their fault, not yours.  Unfortunately I can't see a way to file bug reports on their site, so I guess this erroneous tutorial will continue frustrating learners indefinitely.  Maybe you want to get your tutorials somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a thread a pointer to an object, you must make sure that object remains valid until the thread receiving the pointer is done accessing the object.

Here, you pass the newly-created threads pointers to objects allocated on the stack in `main`. While `main` doesn't return, the thread running it does terminate. After a thread terminates, its stack no longer exists, so it is an error to dereference the pointer after the thread calling `main` calls `pthread_exit`.

You have no synchronization to prevent this from happening. So your code suffers from a race condition.